# How to delete certain condition from data frame

Tags: r, variables, data-cleaning

Lets say this is my df
:

```
people <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
activity <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6)
completion <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
```

And I would like to remove all people that never completed any activity.

I have tried this code, but somehow it does not work. I have no idea what could be wrong here.

```
nevercompleted<- df %>% 
  filter(completion != 0) %>% 
  group_by(people) %>% 
  summarise("frequency activity" = n())

df<- -c (df$nevercompleted)
```

So, in this scenario person 4 should be removed from the df. Note that I am only intrested in removing those that never completed *anything* like person 4, not person 1 who at one point completes an activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Base R

In base R, the following can easily be rewritten as a one-liner.

```
i <- ave(as.logical(df$completion), df$people, FUN = function(x) any(x != 0, na.rm = TRUE))
df <- df[which(i), ]
df
#   people activity completion
#1       1        1          0
#2       1        1          0
#3       1        1          1
#4       2        2          0
#5       2        2          1
#6       3        3          1
#7       3        4          1
#10      5        6          0
#11      5        6          1
```

## 2. Package `dplyr`

And here is a `dplyr` way.

First filter only people that have completed an activity, then join with the original data set in order to get all columns.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(people) %>%
  summarise(completion = any(as.logical(completion))) %>%
  filter(completion) %>%
  select(-completion) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'people')

df
#`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
## A tibble: 9 x 3
#  people activity completion
#   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#1      1        1          0
#2      1        1          0
#3      1        1          1
#4      2        2          0
#5      2        2          1
#6      3        3          1
#7      3        4          1
#8      5        6          0
#9      5        6          1
```

**Data**

In the question there is no `data.frame` instruction, only the creation of the column vectors.

```
people <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
activity <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6)
completion <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
df <- data.frame(people, activity, completion)
```

Comment: @DanielO Yes, it is. I prefer to post like this in order to make it easier to read.

Comment: That's fair. You could make it even easier to read by removing with `with` command, especially since the df is only referenced once anyways. `ave(as.logical(df$completion), people, FUN = function(x) any(x != 0))`

Comment: somehow it is not removed from my df, do i need to add something to remove them or does the code already contain it?

Comment: @Leah Nothing is removed from the df unless you assign the result to it, `df <- code`.

Comment: @DanielO You are right, edited. (But I also coded `df$people`).

Comment: i have added df$i, however nothing happens.. i would like to remove those users where the condition is met

Comment: @Leah No, you haven't understood. See how it is now, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Leah Don't worry, glad to help.

Comment: this just deleted my complete df, i am so confused rn

Comment: @Leah Can you say which of the ways, base or dplyr did you use? You must use one *and only one*.

Comment: @Leah Are there any `NA` values in your data? If yes, see now.

Answer (score 2):

in Base we could do this

```
    byGroup <- split(df,df$people)
    do.call(rbind,byGroup[sapply(byGroup, function(x) !all(x$completion == 0))])

      people activity completion
1.1       1        1          0
1.2       1        1          0
1.3       1        1          1
2.4       2        2          0
2.5       2        2          1
3.6       3        3          1
3.7       3        4          1
5.10      5        6          0
5.11      5        6          1
```

Comment: Note, that i want to only remove those people that never completed anything like person 4, person 1 for example at one point completes the activity.

Comment: @Leah, My answer does exactly that, only person 4 has been removed. All other entries are still there.

Comment: oh, perfect! i will re-run your answer and see if it works :)

Comment: i get the output NULL and nothing in the df changes, what would that mean?

Comment: can you explain why i get this output?

Comment: Do you receive this after the first line or second line? Is your code in a dataframe like you suggested? `df <- data.frame(people, activity, completion)`

Comment: code is in a df and i get this after the second line, but i know for sure that there are a few users who never completed anything. i really like your code and want it to work

Comment: Did you change the code at all? Make sure you do not edit the 2nd line at all. The only thing you might with to change is the first line to reflect the real name of your `df`

Comment: i will check, does this code automatically remove all users that don't fulfill the condition from the df? Thank you for bearing with me

Comment: now i do get output, but nothing is removed from df yet

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(df)` so that we can see your actual data

Answer (score 0):

can be done this way

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(people, activity, completion)

df %>% 
  group_by(people) %>% 
  filter(any(completion != 0))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   people [4]
  people activity completion
   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
1      1        1          0
2      1        1          0
3      1        1          1
4      2        2          0
5      2        2          1
6      3        3          1
7      3        4          1
8      5        6          0
9      5        6          1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code that should work:

```r
library(dplyr)

people <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
activity <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6)
completion <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)

df <- data.frame(people, activity, completion)

df <- filter(df, completion != 0)
```

Result:

```
  people activity completion
1      1        1          1
2      2        2          1
3      3        3          1
4      3        4          1
5      5        6          1
```

This will filter your dataframe to rows whose `completion` variable is not 0.

I'm not sure where you were going with the `group_by` and `summarize`. If you want to do more than remove the rows whose `completion` variable is 0, please clarify that in your question.

Comment: oh, why is the answer so much more simple than my thinking. But would that still keep the people that complete the activity after some time like person 1. I have panel data and only want to delete those that never complete anything

Comment: Yes, it will. The `filter` function here goes row-by-row—it doesn't care about what person 1 has done in other rows. The row where person 1 has a `1` for `completion` will be kept. I added the results to my answer.

Comment: when running it it removed almost all of my users..

Comment: actually, i want to complete all the rows for person 1 if any of them has a 1 for a certain task

Comment: For what rows did your results differ from mine? This solution will remove all rows where the `completion` variable is 0. What do you mean by "complete all the rows"? I'm a bit confused.